# Prevent OpenJDK from overriding Oracle's Java installation

Tags: installation, java, ubuntu-15.04, openjdk

Currently using Lubuntu 15.04 x64. I have had this problem twice now. I install the official Oracle Java (version 1.8) successfully, after which an automatic update (at some point later in the week) uninstalls or overrides my Oracle installation with OpenJDK-1.7.

This is very frustrating since OpenJDK corrupts the Oracle JDK installation. I need to use a specific version of Oracle JDK because the same workspace is shared across multiple computers (of which a few use Windows).

How can I prevent OpenJDK from auto-installing and/or prevent it from overriding the Oracle JDK?

Comment: you've configured your alternatives, right? `sudo update-alternatives --config java` I'm guessing that your oracle install is fine, but it gets unlinked from the alternatives.

Comment: After open-jdk installed itself I used `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of any open-jdk installations. Later when I checked, I saw the /usr/java directory had been fully removed. I assume this was my doing and not open-jdk's. Out of frustration (because I needed Java for some programs) I re-installed open-jdk because I knew it was the quickest and easiest solution. After some more research I have re-installed Oracle's JDK from scratch using this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps). Your comment helped, thx.